# Turn push/pull motion into up/down?

Tags: two-stroke, choke

I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but I have an RC 2 stroke engine with a choke with an arm that requires up/down motion to open/close.

The problem is I can't place a servo below, so I was wondering if anyone knows a way to have at push/pull rod turn into an up/down motion?
(Preferably without any hinges, etc attached to the engine)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm finding it hard to follow you here. There are only two basic ways (I can think of) which would change motion from a horizontal to vertical motion is either with a hinge or redirecting through, such as with a post which you would run a cable over (in essence, this too is a hinge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Bowden cable - think of the cable used for brakes on a bike...

It is flexible and has been used for throttle cables for years...

Connect it to the servo or mechanism on the body or handle bar somewhere...